# After firmware update, pop OS doesnt show in boot menu

Tags: linux, systemd, dual-boot, grub, boot-loader

i was using latest verison of pop OS on my lenovo thinkpad x1 extreme gen 1 and on the settings software it had a new firmware update that fixes a few security stuff and teaks on the CPU.

It said it required a restart to install it so i went through it and it booted into bios with a installation indicator of it installing the new firmware. it was beeping quite a bit during install but after installing this firmware, POP OS disappeared?!?!?

I have two 2tb hdd's inside my system. the first 2tb hdd has dual boot windows and pop OS.

Below are some screenshots showing different partitions i have.

I dual boot to both windows 10 and pop OS that are located in one hdd, and the other hdd has data.

[image]

[image: pop OS is missing]

[image]

I tried following this guide below https://support.system76.com/articles/bootloader/ and it said for me to check the flags for the linux swap partition but as you can see from the first screenshot above, there is no flags set??

I also executed **efibootmgr **  to check the ordering of my efi boots and found no entry for my pop ops ir ay linux of that matter.

```
BootCurrent: 001E
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 001E,0019,001C,001D,001F,0020,0000,0018,001A,0021,001B
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager HD(2,GPT,7b53398e-7279-44b1-9abd-a9ff95b8ee12,0xfa000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...,................
Boot0010 Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0011 Boot Menu FvFile(126a762d-5758-4fca-8531-201a7f57f850)
Boot0012 Diagnostic Splash Screen FvFile(a7d8d9a6-6ab0-4aeb-ad9d-163e59a7a380)
Boot0013 Lenovo Diagnostics FvFile(3f7e615b-0d45-4f80-88dc-26b234958560)
Boot0014 Regulatory Information FvFile(478c92a0-2622-42b7-a65d-5894169e4d24)
Boot0015 Startup Interrupt Menu FvFile(f46ee6f4-4785-43a3-923d-7f786c3c8479)
Boot0016 Rescue and Recovery FvFile(665d3f60-ad3e-4cad-8e26-db46eee9f1b5)
Boot0017 MEBx Hot Key FvFile(ac6fd56a-3d41-4efd-a1b9-870293811a28)
Boot0018* USB CD VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)
Boot0019* USB FDD VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6ff015a28830b543a8b8641009461e49)
Boot001A* NVMe0 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,001c199932d94c4eae9aa0b6e98eb8a400)
Boot001B* NVMe1 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,001c199932d94c4eae9aa0b6e98eb8a401)
Boot001C* ATA HDD0 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f601)
Boot001D* ATA HDD1 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f602)
Boot001E* USB HDD VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,33e821aaaf33bc4789bd419f88c50803)
Boot001F* PCI LAN VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d3803)
Boot0020 Other CD VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,aea2090adfde214e8b3a5e471856a35406)
Boot0021 Other HDD VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f606)
Boot0022* IDER BOOT CDROM PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(15,1)
Boot0023* IDER BOOT Floppy PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(15,0)
Boot0024* ATA HDD VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f6)
Boot0025* ATAPI CD VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,aea2090adfde214e8b3a5e471856a354)
Boot0026* PCI LAN VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d380
```

3)

Any suggestions on how i could fix this?

My files are still intact but for some strange reason, my laptop does not identify as a booting option no more

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: yup i had to fix the bootloader, there is instructions on the system76 website